# Get information from user who signed in for course

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get a list off users under the Deelnemers: who signed up for the course. I'm not sure how to do this have been trying for a while now. 
Database looks like the picture down below.
[image: database]

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/mysql_config.php');
$id = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : header('location: login.php');
$Cursist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']);

require_once('header.php');
$cursus = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM cursus WHERE id =".$_GET['id']));
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="post-preview">
          <h2 class="post-title">
            <?php echo $cursus['title'] . "<br />";?>
            <?php echo $cursus['beginDatum'] . "<br />";?>
            Deelnemers:
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users t WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM aanmeldingen B WHERE t.id = b.user_id)"));
            $amount = mysqli_affected_rows($con);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
              $user = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

            echo $user['email']. "<br />";
          }?>
          </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can i get this to work since i dont know how to do this anymore

Comment: so, what is the error and what do you expect from the code..? pondering at the query `SELECT * FROM users t WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM aanmeldingen B WHERE t.id = b.user_id)`, looks like you're trying to retrieve user and it's related cursus?

Comment: what do you mean with "Deelnemers", I don't see it in your code/database with that word.

Comment: @Luuk, it's on the code, use ctrl+f, at first i didn't find it too.

anyway marjin, you might want a reference on [many-to-many relationship](http://lornajane.net/posts/2011/inner-vs-outer-joins-on-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: I would like to get a list of users that are related to a cursus

Comment: the page has page.php?id=4 in its url and with the _get i get the specific cursus

Comment: why not use join?

Comment: you could use join or just a select.. like `select * from users where id in (select user_id from aanmeldigen where cursus_id = ?)`. if you wish entire course with their related users, i suggest you read the link that i put on my earlier comment - the many-to-many relationship - or just simply google-out *many-to-many relationship using join* in google.

Comment: Actually you're selecting any user who's signed in for any course. You do not specify that you want only the users from the coursepage that you're actually on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql

```
SELECT cursus.id, aanmeldingen.cursus_id, aanmeldingen.users_id, users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN (cursus INNER JOIN aanmeldingen ON cursus.id = aanmeldingen.cursus_id) ON users.id = aanmeldingen.users_id
WHERE cursus.id = 'ID number of the cursus';
```

1. The Table cursus makes contact with aanmeldingen
2. The Table aanmeldingen makes contact with users
3. By WHERE cursus id = given id number, I can get the a all information of the users who are member of the given cursus

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reorganizing your database to just 3 tables - users, cursus and cursusstudent.

email in users is unique for every user so that they can use it with their password to login.

cursus:
db_id, cursus_id, naam_cursus, beschrijving, begindatum, cursussoort, prijs

cursusstudent:
db_id, cursus_id, email
(The email column here should not be unique because one student can be in more than one course)

To get list of users with related cursus :
1. Query cursusstudent

$sql_student_and_cursus_id = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cursusstudent");

// Declare the name of the list variable
$list = "";

2. Save the cursus_id and email in a while loop. Inside the loop, query cursus for the current cursus_id and also query users for the current email.
   Get their respective naam_cursus and name. Save them in the list variable.

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_student_and_cursus_id) > 0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_student_and_cursus_id)){

```
$cursus_id = $row['cursus_id'];
$email = $row['email'];
```

// Collect cursus name
$query_cursus = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT naam_cursus FROM cursus WHERE cursus_id = '$cursus_id'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_cursus) > 0){

while($row_cursus_naam = mysqli_fetch_array($query_cursus)){

```
$naam_cursus = $row_cursus_naam['naam_cursus'];

        }
    }
```

// Collect name of user
$query_users = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_users) > 0){

while($row_naam_user = mysqli_fetch_array($query_users)){

```
$naam_user = $row_naam_user['name'];

        }
    }
```

// Save them in the list
$list .= $naam_user . ' ' . $naam_cursus;
    }

}

3. Display the list outside the loop:

if(isset($list)){

echo $list;

}